# Использование клиентского сертификата .p12 в API-запросах (Python)

Tags: python, openssl, сертификат

Всем привет! Для запросов к API имеется сертификат p12, который защищён паролем. Успешно добавила этот сертификат в браузер, запросы через Swagger выполняются. Теперь пытаюсь прикрутить этот сертификат к автотестам вот таким образом:
`res = requests.post(url, headers=default_headers, cert='pkcs12_197.p12')`, не выходит, т.к. нужно каким-то образом добавить ключ.
Нашла решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163100/p12-cert-authenticate-python , но при использовании ловлю:

> "DeprecationWarning: PKCS#12 support in pyOpenSSL is deprecated. You
> should use the APIs in cryptography.   p12 =
> crypto.load_pkcs12(open("pkcs12_197.p12", 'rb').read(),
> certpw.encode())"

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как реализовать подобное с библиотекой cryptography? Необходимо получить пару (cert, key).

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сама на свой вопрос. Решение можно найти здесь:
[Экспорт сертификатов и закрытого ключа из файла PKCS # 12 с помощью OpenSSL](https://www.ssl.com/ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-pkcs12-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-openssl/)

Необходимо воспользоваться утилитой openssl в Linux-окружении. Файлы .crt и .key передаются в виде кортежа при запросе.

```
clientcert = ('cert-file.crt', 'key-file.key')
res = requests.post(url, cert=clientcert)
```